# Adding program to startup registry folder not working (C#)

Tags: c#, registry, startup

I'm attempting to use this code to run my program at startup

```
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.runonstartup)
 {
      key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
      key.SetValue("PrintScreenSharp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
      key.Close();
      }
 else
 {
      key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
      key.DeleteValue("PrintScreenSharp");
 }
```

It adds and removes the key without any problems, but when I restart the computer the program does not run. If you check Task Manager it has my program listed and enabled, but it's actually labeled as "program", oddly. It does not mention it by its real name "PrintScreen#".

I've been looking for some time as to why this may be, but I've had no luck.

Here is the program if you wanted to try it yourself:

http://box.endurehosting.com/contents/public/PrintScreen%23.exe

Comment: Any chance its failing due to the run group potentially kicking in before everything is ready? any log files from your app to look at?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've checked the event log and see no mention of my program. I feel I should mention as well the copy of windows I'm running was installed 5 hours ago. Just about as stock as it can get.

Comment: have you considered putting it in the run on login under scheduled tasks? also have you tried a dummy app that does next to nothing and just say writes to a temp file to say "I did this" to confirm it was working - Im thinking its kicking in before the desktop is really available

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is not visible and the code you provided should be working alright, I'm offering an alternative which might look ugly to you but it's worth a shot. You can create a shortcut and place it into the "Startup" folder in order to add it, or remove the shortcut in order to stop it from starting up.

You can achieve the creating of a shortcut by doing:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
```

And then include this outside of your class:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
internal class ShellLink
{
}
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
internal interface IShellLink
{
    void GetPath([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszFile, int cchMaxPath, out IntPtr pfd, int fFlags);
    void GetIDList(out IntPtr ppidl);
    void SetIDList(IntPtr pidl);
    void GetDescription([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszName, int cchMaxName);
    void SetDescription([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);
    void GetWorkingDirectory([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszDir, int cchMaxPath);
    void SetWorkingDirectory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDir);
    void GetArguments([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszArgs, int cchMaxPath);
    void SetArguments([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszArgs);
    void GetHotkey(out short pwHotkey);
    void SetHotkey(short wHotkey);
    void GetShowCmd(out int piShowCmd);
    void SetShowCmd(int iShowCmd);
    void GetIconLocation([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszIconPath, int cchIconPath, out int piIcon);
    void SetIconLocation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszIconPath, int iIcon);
    void SetRelativePath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPathRel, int dwReserved);
    void Resolve(IntPtr hwnd, int fFlags);
    void SetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile);
}
```

And then in order to use it, you can simply call it:

```
IShellLink link = (IShellLink)new ShellLink();
link.SetDescription("description here");
link.SetPath(Application.ExecutablePath);

IPersistFile file = (IPersistFile)link;
string StartupFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
file.Save(Path.Combine(StartupFolderPath, "NAME OF SHORTCUT.lnk"), false);
```

You can get the string path to startup folder using:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
```

This should create a shortcut and place it into the startup folder path. As I said it is not an elegant solution, but if you cannot find the root of your problem when adding the registry, this is worth the shot.